# Navigation Component is giving me a weird issue

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

So, I'm trying to migrate my project to Navigation Components, but I'm having a weird isse.

I added a new fragment that host my main menu. This fragment is called `fragment_main_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

It has its own `Fragment` activity

```
class MainMenuFragment: Fragment(), MainMenuContract.MainMenuView {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu,container,false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```

Now, there are two problems.

1.- I cannot add to hte fragment_main_menu any `tools:context=""` with my fragment activity because its not reachable.

2.- I cant find my fragment_main_menu inside the nav_graph.xml and I cant keep on with migrating.

[image]

What is happening ?

Comment: A temporary fix that I found is to do it manually from the text editor :/

Comment: You refer to fragments by their class name (i.e., `MainMenuFragment`), not by the name of their resource file.

Comment: but there is not render for that in my nav_graph , hmm , let me check out

Comment: So your Fragment is already added to the navigation graph - it just doesn't have a preview?

Comment: No, I cant see the fragment into the graph search, But if I place it with code from the editor it does pop up